# Error testing HTTPS response server in PayPal IPN simulator

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

My IPN Listener is protected by SSL, and access to a host via HTTPS, I try to test it using PayPal IPN simulator, but it gives an error: `IPN Delivery Failed: I / O error: HTTPS hostname wrong: should be <xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx>; nested exception is java.io.IOException: HTTPS hostname wrong: should be <xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx>`. Where `<xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx>` - IP address of my server. If I use an unsecured connection via HTTP, I get a response on this IP with IPN simulator, ports 80, 443 open. I try to go to the IPN Listener through a browser, I successfully opened IPN Listener JSP page through HTTPS. Tell me whether the PayPal with SSL hosts on which the IPN Listener or what could be my problem??

Comment: Are you sure the SSL is setup to protect the IP address that your test server is running on?

Comment: Yes, because I go to the JSP successfully IPN Listener page and the browser tells me that the open web service using HTTPS, while IPN Listener writes in the log that the call was from a web browser, but when you try to use the IPN Simulator, or he does not call my service at all or that it will not let me, I can not understand (((

Comment: But if you don't have anything setup to specifically reject situations where your hostname doesn't actually match the IP address like PayPal seems to then it would still run without any issue.  What is the hostname you're working with?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, PayPal with HTTPS is working properly and the problem is that PayPal requires a specific domain name, not an IP address?

Comment: I'm really not sure, but it sounds like something is wrong with the SSL or the host you're using.  For example, if the SSL was configured to run on https://some.domain.com which resolves to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, but then you're running from an IP address that doesn't match.

It's not something I've ever specifically tested but that's just an odd error you're getting so that's all I can think of.

Comment: Do not have a domain name server (host name), I am requesting a test server over IP, for example: `https://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/MyIPNListener/`, the same as I do and for the HTTP request: `http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/MyIPNListener/`, with the IPN simulator responds to an HTTP request "IPN sent success", but on the HTTPS gives an error message described in the head. I think that PayPal does not work with self-signed certificates, or it is absolutely necessary for the HTTPS domain name, not the IP, because it works and communicates via an HTTPS web service is.

Comment: Can you email me the full URL you're using in the simulator? I haven't seen this error before - I'll investigate this. Email is in my profile. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a defect on our end. We'll get this fixed.
Thanks for bringing it to our attention!