# Trouble with PayPal IPN Service. IPN Simulator not giving expected result

Tags: java, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am trying to use the [PayPal IPN service](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/). I have set up my Notification URL (herein referred to as 'my page') to respond to the IPN and validate the request as instructed. In addition, my page sends me an email regardless of the status of the IPN. It appears to work as expected *unless* I test via the [PayPal IPN Simulator](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/ipn_simulator).

**These are my findings. Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong and how I can get this to work as expected in the IPN simulator (case 3 and 4)?**

**Case 1)** I go to my page in-browser (http *or* https) passing no params:

> Result = **as expected**: PayPal's IPN service responds 'INVALID' and my page sends me an email.

**Case 2)** I go to my page in-browser (http *or* https) and pass the sample params detailed in the [integration guide](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/):

> Result = **as expected**: PayPal's IPN service responds 'INVALID' and my page sends me an email of all the details.

**Case 3)** I use the [PayPal IPN Simulator](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/ipn_simulator) and test my page over *insecure* protocol (http):

> Result = **PARTIALLY as expected**: The service says '*IPN sent successfully*'  but my page **does not** send me an email (suggesting it wasn't in fact called at all).
>   **Expecting**: '*IPN sent successfully*' and my page to send an email.

**Case 4)** I use the [PayPal IPN Simulator](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/ipn_simulator) and test my page over a *secure* protocol (https):

> Result = **NOT as expected**: The service says '*We're sorry, we could not send an IPN*' and my page **does not** send me an email (suggesting no attempt was made or the URL wasn't reachable).
>   **Expecting**: '*IPN sent successfully*' and my page to send an email.

I found [this related unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20015292/why-doesnt-paypals-ipn-simulator-work-with-https-addresses) and [this q&a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17912563/error-testing-https-response-server-in-paypal-ipn-simulator) but nothing else useful. Any help would be much appreciated. Perhaps I'm missing something fundamental. I have to admit to struggling a little with the various API's and instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Case 3 = My Bad (ish).**

There was an uncaught error that would only happen when called via the simulator. My code was expecting the charset encoding to be passed in the param `charset` (as per PayPal's own example) but it wasn't and my sloppy coding didn't account for the possibility of it being `null`.

**Case 4 = Expired SSL Certificate**

My SSL Certificate was no longer valid. I haven't actually tested it with a valid certificate but I expect its highly likely that this is the problem.